# Calling function // expected primary-expression before "]" token

Tags: c++

```
`#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 #define N 10

 void QuickSort(int arr[],int left,int right)
{
int i = left, j = right;
int buffer;
int middle = arr[(left+right)/2];

//partition
while(i<=j)
{
    while(arr[i]<middle)
        i++;
    while(arr[j]>middle)
        j--;
    if(i<=j)
    {
        buffer = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = buffer;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

//recursion
 if (left < j)
    QuickSort(arr, left, j);
 if (i < right)
    QuickSort(arr, i, right);
}

int main()
{

  int A[N] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
  QuickSort(A[],A,A+N);     //ERROR
  return 0;

}`
```

Ok,guys - here is my question. I can't really get how to call the function to sort a standart  non-dynamic array. When I try to call QuickSort(int A[],int left, int right) with QuickSort(A[],A,A+N) an error that says " expected primary-expression before "]" token " occurs. 
Thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: Nah, this is not a good question for SO. You are supposed to make the effort to at least learn language basics.

Comment: this is how to make BIG entrance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use braces when passing arrays to functions, also it seems your code should be:

```
QuickSort(A,0,0+N);
```

Answer (score 2):

just pass in A. like this. also your second and third parameters are int values, so while i wont dive into the logic of your code, you should choose aninteger to provide bounds to your array sort. what you are passing in now is an int * to the first element in the array, and then the third parameter is that value + N. BAD NEWS BEARS!

```
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 #define N 10

 void QuickSort(int arr[],int left,int right)
{
int i = left, j = right;
int buffer;
int middle = arr[(left+right)/2];

//partition
while(i<=j)
{
    while(arr[i]<middle)
        i++;
    while(arr[j]>middle)
        j--;
    if(i<=j)
    {
        buffer = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = buffer;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}

//recursion
 if (left < j)
    QuickSort(arr, left, j);
 if (i < right)
    QuickSort(arr, i, right);
}

int main()
{

  int A[N] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
  QuickSort(A,0,N);     //DO THIS
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Worked. Ty very much for the response :)

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Pass `A` by itself.
2. `left` and `right` are array indexes, not pointers.

Give this a try:

```
int A[N] = {10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
QuickSort(A, 0, N - 1); // array length N means the last element is index N-1.
```

Comment: Worked. Ty very much for the response :)